# class attritbute naming convention which is expecting a class instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting, format, pep8

I am working with developing a code base in Python and am wondering something about a class attribute naming convention. I am using the PEP8 standard:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

http://pep8.org/

for all of my code. I am wondering however about a specific convention for a class attribute name. During your class initialization all of the class default attribute get defined. These attributes all follow the naming conventions in the standard, or well they should.

However I am wondering about cases where a class attribute is an instance of another class. Should this attribute name follow the snake case system of a class attribute or the camel case system of a class?

I.E.

```
class ExampleClass(HigherClass):
    def __init(self, class_attribute=None)
```

or

```
class ExampleClass(HigherClass):
    def __init(self, ClassAttribute=None)
```

where class_attribute/ClassAttribute are expected, and later in the code forced to be a specific instance of the class ClassAttribute defined elsewhere in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Classes and instances are different concepts with different naming conventions. If you're using ThisCase for the instances of classes you define, you're doing it wrong.